# SQL Rounding Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, rounding

I have been doing alot of research attempting to find an answer to my question.

I am trying to work out which syntax is needed to round when the figure is less than one.

For example 
             SELECT 17/26

When running this in SQL, it bring up zero, however i am attempting to get it to return me an answer of 0.65.

I have tried using ROUND, CAST AS Numeric,Decimal and also Money.

So far.... no luck

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you mention `money`, is this [tag:sql-server]? Also, casting to the other types should have worked - do you still have the attempts around, such that you can include the actual attempts in your question?

Comment: Are you casting the numerator and denominator or the result? I suspect you are casting the result of the integer division.

Comment: Normally the equation is done by 2 variables for instance "@Value1/@Value2". But because on this result, it was pulling back a figure less than zero this didnt work. I have been cast "SELECT CAST (17/26 AS Numeric (10,2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT round(convert(float,17)/26,2)
```

Comment: Brilliant :). That has worked. For future reference, can you explain to me how and why this has worked. I have been using SQL at work for 9 months now and really getting into and want to carry on learning. I would appreciate any explanation, Thanks in advance

Comment: You have converted your output to float and hence it has not been working for you. You need to convert your numerator or denominator to float before division to get your output in float. After that, just round it to 2 decimals. Hope that's clear for you :)

Comment: Yeah that pretty much makes sense to me :). Thank you for the help, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it's worth, when I'm doing something like this with an actual hard-coded value I just add a decimal place to one of the elements. A `CAST()` is better for a database field, but if you're typing something in just use a decimal ...

```
 SELECT 17/26, 17/26.0, 17.0/26
```

Answer (score 0):

try force engine to manage floats (multiplying with float number '1.0') like this...

```
SELECT (1.0*17/26) as x;
```

also to round... you can write it like

```
SELECT round((1.0*17/26),2) as x;
```

(tried on PostgreSQL and worked)